# Sandboxed code execution request failed error

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online

I have developed a webpart, deployed to local tested successfully. I've then added the WSP to my live environment (SP 2010 Online) but when I try to add in my webpart to a page i get the following pop up error.

"Sandboxed code execution request failed error"

Very strange...so I thought it may be my code...so I go through the whole process again but with just a simple webpart with NO code, just my name in a H1 tag.

Same error.

I have been developing webparts like these for the last year without any kind of issue. Has anyone experienced this before?

TIA

S

Answer (score 1):

Verify following things:

1. Check if your sandbox service is started
2. Check if the account running sandbox service has permission on the site collection where you're developing the site.
3. Debug with the user code service process and check if your code is accessing something which it is not allowed.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: thanks for the post, turned out it was an issue with Microsoft, they had to fix it! thankfully nothing to do with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Is this issue occurring only for one particular webpart? Or for all webparts?

This is most probably due to not enough resource points being allotted to the Site Collection on which you are trying to add the web part. Or it might be the case that all the resource points allotted are being consumed by other solutions if there are any.

You can increase the number of resource points allocated from the SharePoint online admin console. Find out more details here:
http://community.zevenseas.com/Blogs/Vardhaman/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=5